# Convexity of $2$-Normed Space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

**2-Normed Space Uniformly Convex**

$2$-Normed Space $(L, \Vert \cdot  , \cdot  \Vert)$ is said ***uniformly convex*** if for every $\epsilon >0$, exist $\delta(\epsilon) >0$ such that $\Vert x,z \Vert = \Vert y,z \Vert = 1$, $\Vert x-y, z \Vert \ge \epsilon, x \not = y$ and $z \not \in V(x,y)$ then $$\Big \Vert \frac{x+y}{2}, z \Big \Vert \le (1-\delta(\epsilon)).$$

**2-Normed Space Strictly Convex**

Let ($X, \Vert \cdot , \cdot  \Vert $) be a $2$-normed space. Then
$(X, \Vert \cdot, \cdot \Vert)$ is said to be ***strictly convex*** if for every $x,y,z\in X$ satisfying
$\Vert x, z \Vert = \Vert y,z \Vert = 1$, $x\not=y$, $z \not \in V(x,y)$,
\emph{we have} $\Vert \frac{x+y}{2}, z \Vert < \frac{1}{2}(\Vert x,z \Vert + \Vert y,z \Vert ) <1$.

**Theorem: Uniform Convex Implies Strictly Convex**

Given $(X, \Vert \cdot, \cdot \Vert)$ uniformly convex. Then for every $\epsilon >0$ exist $\delta(\epsilon) >0$ such that $\Vert x,z \Vert = \Vert y,z \Vert = 1$, $\Vert x-y, z \Vert \ge \epsilon, x \not = y$ dan $z \not \in V(x,y)$. We obtain $$\Big \Vert \frac{x+y}{2}, z \Big \Vert \le (1-\delta(\epsilon)) < 1.$$

**Question**

What about the converse?
Is strictly convex implies uniform convex?

Comment: In short, I want to find a norm that strictly convex **but not** uniformly convex. 

I did some experiment. 
We know that $\Vert x \Vert_1$ (taxicab norm) is strictly convex. 
How can we proof (or disproof), that norm is not uniformly?

Comment: Anyway, I found the link:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3676863/show-that-e-is-not-uniform-convex-space

My problem is solved. 
Thanks in advance @geetha290krm